# Limit retry count of Authenticator

Tags: android, okhttp

I extended `Authenticator` to retrieve the authorization and authentication tokens when I get the authentication challenge (401). It retries 20 times. Is there a way to set a different count (I'd like to set it to 3)?

Just in case it's relevant, I'm using OkHttp(3) with retrofit2.

Comment: how did you come up with 20?

Comment: @Blackbelt from this https://github.com/square/okhttp/pull/1256 and it seems to match the number of requests I saw in the logs though I didn't count them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [Handling Authentication](https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#handling-authentication-kt-java) documentation:

```
private int responseCount(Response response) {
  int result = 1;
  while ((response = response.priorResponse()) != null) {
    result++;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It would be great if that information was more accessible. It's hard to find buried in "recipes".

Comment: Note: The retry logic is only included in the Java version of the example code, that @Jesse Wilson linked to - not in the Kotlin version.

Answer (score 2):

I made an extension function for the Response object in Kotlin. Since I'm only interested in trying three times before giving up.

```
private val Response.reachedMaxAttempts: Boolean
    get() = this.priorResponse?.priorResponse?.priorResponse != null
```